# Error в ajax запросе и статус 200

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

В моей функции выполняется ajax запрос:

```
var $that = $('#careerform'),
    formData = new FormData($that.get(0));
$.ajax({
    url: $that.attr('action'),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log('work');
        $('#modal-career').modal('hide');
        $('#send-careermail').show();
        $('.career-spinner-sending').hide();
        var loccheck = localStorageCheck();
        if (loccheck == true) {
            localStorage.pricesend = 1;
            window.location = '/careers?p=careers';
        } else {
            setTimeout(function () {
                showModalCareersNotif();
                $('#close-modal-thanks').click(function () {
                    $('#modal-thanks-price').modal('hide');
                });
            }, 500);
        }
        $('#careername').val('');
        $('#careersurname').val('');
        $('#careerphone').val('');
        $('#careermail').val('');
        $('#careermessage').val('');
        $('#careerfile').val('');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error', data);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

В консоли мне выдает ошибку, при этом со статусом 200. Модальное окно не пропадает, и что самое интересное - в админку вакансии все равно приходят.
В чем может быть причина?

[image: error]

Comment: Ошибку в студию! То бишь в вопрос

Comment: @Darth, дополнил вопрос скрином.

Comment: У вас ответ пустой, думаю в этом причина, у вас datatype стоит json, а в ответ не дошел. при этом пхп все верно записывает в базу

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, ок, спасибо за подсказку. Как можно сделать ответ не пустым?

Comment: на серверной стороне, где пишите в базу, после записи отправляете json. Либо удалите в своем запросе `dataType: 'json'`, тогда скорее всего пройдет в success

Answer (score 1):

Помогло вот такое решение:

заменил `dataType: 'json'` на `dataType: 'text'`.